# CSS for adaptive site, often broken on standard resolution

Tags: css, tablet

I'm making and adaptive website, and I load time by time the CSS file, based on the resolution of the  screen.

But I'm struggling to have it correctly executed on all the platforms. I have not clue where I wrong

Please, let me make some example

Into the index.html file, I put this selector among tha other ones:

```
  <link type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 2001px) and (max-width: 2499px)" href="css/2048-1536.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then I load it into a Tablet, that has resolution 2048x1536
And it should be loaded the related CSS file.

instead of the site is broken. All the objects are wrongly placed and not any object is in order.
Then I test it with Google Chrome **F12 > Emulation > Device** and I put the resolution up there. And it works fine.

Also just shrinking the browser it works ... thus I have not clue what to do in order to make it work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<link type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 2001px) and (max-width: 2499px)" href="css/2048-1536.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hi tehnuty.I tried but without result.

I checked with a Sony and an IcoTab Quadcore.

Sony is 2048 x 1536, while the IcoTab is 1280 x 800

The site is broken like it doesn't load any CSS, in fact.

Comment: It should work. It does for me. For more of media attribute check : 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp